# How to retrieve the data in POST header into the variable?

Tags: dart

In PHP, I can get the data from the submitted form. From the POST or GET header. If I don't want to show user the data (GET), I use the POST. I can extract the POST data in this way:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="data">
  <button type="submit">
</form>
```

```php
if(!empty($_POST)){
  $variable=$_POST["name"];
  print($variable); //data
}
```

**How to do it in Dart?**

Answer (score 2):

If the content has been url-encoded you can use [Uri.splitQueryString](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Uri.html#splitQueryString) on the content.

```dart
UTF8.decodeStream(request).then((content) {
  final params = Uri.splitQueryString(content);
  print(params['name']);
});
```